# Python Selenium switch_to.frame() isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, iframe, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to get text from the website.
iframe is in HTML, so I tried .switch_to.frame() but failed.

In this website(https://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_trans_style.nhn), there are several iframes but the one with @name = 'day' is only one. (xpath : //*[@name='day'])

So I tried switch_to.frame() and get element in the iframe.

But the result

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_trans_style.nhn' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
column_list = []

try : 
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(1)


iframe = driver.find_element_by_name('day')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

time.sleep(1)

for n in range(4,9):
    for i in range(1,12):

        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[n]/td[i]').text
        column_list.append(element)

except Exception as e :
    print(e)

finally : 
    driver.quit()

print(column_list)
```

I expect a column_list that has many float element. 
But the result was like this..

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[n]/td[i]"}

It seems that message says I didn't actually switch_to.frame(ifrmae). But I have no clues why I failed..

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate variables into string

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[' + str(n) + ']/td[' + str(i) +']').text
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh!  Thanks a lot!!